# targeting file using relative path on mvc app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to access to the file on my web project under content folder, and I want to use relative path. Can someone confirm me that I'm using right approach

```
string file = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

yes its 100% right.
**When you execute the code outside the context of a http request then HttpContext.Current is null and your code crashes. HostingEnvironment.MapPath always works**

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario i have used this approach to get multiple files and it worked fine ,so i recommend this .
try it once

```
 String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "\\Videos\\");
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt to use `Path.Combine` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx